# Tensorflow Quantization Aware Training : How to check weights for Custom Quantize Config

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to Quantize my CNN model for 4 bits using QAT and I am using Custom Quantize Config and giving it to custom quantized scope.

However, weights are still in floating point values when we try to see them. Can someone let me know why is this the case and how to check weights for 4 bit levels?

```
class DefaultQuantizeConfig(tfmot.quantization.keras.QuantizeConfig):
    # Configure how to quantize weights.
    def get_weights_and_quantizers(self, layer):
      return [(layer.kernel, LastValueQuantizer(num_bits=4, symmetric=True, narrow_range=False, per_axis=False))]

    # Configure how to quantize activations.
    def get_activations_and_quantizers(self, layer):
      return [(layer.activation, MovingAverageQuantizer(num_bits=4, symmetric=False, narrow_range=False, per_axis=False))]

    def set_quantize_weights(self, layer, quantize_weights):
      layer.kernel = quantize_weights[0]

    def set_quantize_activations(self, layer, quantize_activations):
      layer.activation = quantize_activations[0]

    # Configure how to quantize outputs (may be equivalent to activations).
    def get_output_quantizers(self, layer):
      return []

    def get_config(self):
      return {}


quant_model =Sequential([
        quantize_annotate_layer(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)), DefaultQuantizeConfig()),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        quantize_annotate_layer(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'), DefaultQuantizeConfig()),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
#         tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_annotate_layer(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 1), activation='relu'), DefaultQuantizeConfig()),
#         tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_annotate_layer(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 1)), DefaultQuantizeConfig()) if is_quantizable(MaxPooling2D()) else MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 1)),
        quantize_annotate_layer(Flatten()),
       quantize_annotate_layer(Dense(10, activation='softmax'), DefaultQuantizeConfig())
    ])
)

# Compile and train your model as usual
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


with tf.keras.utils.custom_object_scope(
  {'DefaultQuantizeConfig': DefaultQuantizeConfig}):
  # Use `quantize_apply` to actually make the model quantization aware.
  quantized_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_apply(quant_model)
    
    
quantized_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
quantized_model.summary()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.